# Using `defer` or `only` on ForeignKey

Tags: django

I'm trying to squeeze a few milliseconds from a view. I'd like to avoid loading some pretty large text fields from a `ForeignKey` model that I won't use.

To make it clearer:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    text1 = models.TextField()
    text2 = models.TextField()
    ...

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('foo_detail', (), {"object_id": self.pk, "object_slug": self.slug})


class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    ...
```

Then in a template:

```
 {% for bar in bars %}
      {{ bar.foo.get_absolute_url }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Now, if you look at the queries issued by the orm, for each `foo` Django retrieves every field (as expected), but in the end only `pk` and `slug` are needed. In my case, that sums up to more or less a hundredth of a second per object on my testing machine.

Of course I could write a method like this:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_foo_absolute_url(self):
        return Foo.objects.only('pk', 'slug').get(pk=self.foo).get_absolute_url()
```

and use it in the template, but it's ugly as hell.

Did anyone face the same problem and come up with a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issue, but we moved to another solution - cached URL in memcache/state cache or precalculated in model field.

We tested out that reverse of URL, which *models.permalink* does, is lowering performance.

Comment: Actually, afaik, the slowness of `reverse` has been addressed quite a few years ago. I ran some tests just to be sure and it takes on average 94.2 µs on my laptop, that is 2 order of magnitude faster than retrieving large text field from the db. Caching the urls might be a faster solution, but still I'm wondering if there is a way to defer some fields when loading a related object through dot notation.

Comment: correct, last time we tested reverse performance 3 years ago. But we have complex URL scheme and logic to create permalinks for multiple locations.

Comment: I've just realized, that what you request is a core of Django, since you perform a call to object method, and django tries it best making available all the fields values. To solve this, classmethod/non-model method is required. Or core decorator to tell which fields to use. I'd prefer classmethod/your solution